# Open file with a particular extension

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, glob

Using PowerShell, I want to open an excel using * instead of filename. The below code fails at line 2. Looking to open file with extension *.xlsx

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$FilePath_Excel = "C:\Users\Documents\FILES\*.xlsx"
$workbook2 = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath_Excel)
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("Jan.xlsm!EOL")
$Excel.Workbooks.Close()
$excel.Quit()
```

with the below error

> ```
> Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Users\Documents\FILES\*.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or 
> deleted?
> At C:\Users\Documents\FILES\Untitled1.ps1:7 char:1
> + $workbook2 = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath_Excel)
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> ```

Comment: Use the absolute file path for the excel file. Excel's `Workbooks.Open` method cannot handle wildcards

Comment: You cannot open an workbook in this way! But, you can use `Dir` in order to iterate between all files in a folder. `Dir` will send a full qualified path for each workbook...

Comment: `$excel.Workbooks.Open((Resolve-Path -Path $FilePath_Excel |Select -First 1).ProviderPath)`